# Components of Kontsevich moduli space of stable maps and reducible curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, fano-varieties

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a smooth projective variety which is Fano and $M_{0,0}(X,e)$ the (projective) Kontsevich moduli space of rational curves of degree $e>1$. Is it possible (or are there examples) for an irreducible component whose general member is a generically injective morphism $\mathbb P^1\rightarrow X$ to contain no reducible rational curve?

Comment: There are silly examples where you embed $X$ by a positive integer multiple $e>1$ of an ample invertible sheaf.  Then the degree of every curve is divisible by $e$.  So even the "minimal" curves have degree $\geq e$.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems almost certain (based on parameter counts) that for every Fano complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^n$, for every $e>1$, every irreducible component of $\overline{M}_{0,0}(X,e)$ intersects the locus parameterizing reducible rational curves.  Maybe the question has a positive answer if $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ generates the Picard group of $X$.

Comment: Is it sufficient to say that $\bar{M}_{0,0}(X,e)\subset \bar{M}_{0,0}(\mathbb P^n,e)$ and that $\bar{M}_{0,0}(\mathbb P^n,e)$ is irreducible with divisors (hence with nonempty intersection with a complete curve) corresponding to maps with reducible domains?

Comment: "Is it sufficient to say ..."  To what are you referring?  As my example shows, it is *not* true that every complete curve intersects the boundary of $\overline{M}_{0,0}(\mathbb{P}^n,e)$.  In fact, there exists a (projective) contraction of the boundary of $\overline{M}_{0,0}(\mathbb{P}^n,e)$ discovered independenty by Anca and Andrei Mustata, by Adam Parker, and by Izzet Coskun, Joe Harris and myself.  So, even for Fano complete intersections, a general point of $\overline{M}_{0,0}(X,e)$ is contained in a curve  that does not intersect the boundary.